# Use two packages with the same dependency

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-eslint

I have two packages  "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin" and eslint-config-react-app. Currently when I use both of them I get an error

```
ESLint couldn't determine the plugin "@typescript-eslint" uniquely.
Please remove the "plugins" setting from either config or remove either plugin installation.
```

b eacuse both packages have the dependency @typescript-eslint 
How do I make this work ?
I already added the

```
"extends": [
    "react-app",
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"
  ],
"plugins": ["@typescript-eslint"],
"root": "true"
```

to my .eslintrc.json.

Comment: same issue, did you find a solution?